# What is this algebraic structure called like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, order-theory

Is there a name for an object $L$ that has an additive structure and a (not necessarily total) order such that for all $a,b,c \in $ L we have

1. $a+b = b+a$
2. $a+(b+c)= (a+b)+c $
3. $a+b \leq a+c \Leftrightarrow b \leq c$

Comment: commutative and ordered semigroup

Comment: @Wuestenfux That's a complete answer. Please put it as a solution to keep unanswered searches clear!

Comment: is it not the case that for commutative and ordered semigroups the implaction $\Rightarrow$ must not hold in 3. ?

Comment: @rschwieb According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_semigroup), in an ordered semigroup, it is enough that $b \leq c$ implies that $a+b \leq a+c$; the reverse inequality may not hold.

Comment: @amrsa OK, this is true. I guess one thing is missing, considering the lack of inverses.

Comment: Maybe there is no name for this very specific situation, but it is certainly an ordered semigroup. It just has something more...

Comment: @amrsa Still, even if slightly incomplete, it is worth pitching as a probable answer. We don't even know if the user intentionally wanted that implication. It could just as easily been a reflexive typo.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, you're right. And I'm also in favor of providing answers, even if a complete answer can be given in a comment. Wuestenflux could, for example, state as an answer what (s)he stated in the comment, with the additional info that that equivalence is not really needed (just one implication).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the structure is a commutative and ordered semigroup.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Hi: it looks like you have reviewed hastily. It is, in fact, probably the most straightforward answer possible.